# Exception for 'NOT LIKE' in Oracle_SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

in a database are many tables with the name 'D_...'.
In a search query, all tables with 'D_%' should be ignored, except one. How do I handle this exception?

Comment: Maybe you should use `OR` ...

Comment: I've removed the Django tag; if it is relevant to the question then you need to [edit] the question to show how it is relevant.

Comment: Are you want to filter database tables or records of tables?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well, you would need something like this sql.
Adding ***escape option*** to ***not like*** clause will make oracle consider "_" as a simple character.

```sql
select * 
from user_tables
where table_name not like 'D/_%' escape '/'  
  or table_name in ('YOUR_EXCEPTION_TABLE_NAME')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT LIKE` and escape the underscore:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  your_column NOT LIKE 'D\_%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table (your_column) AS
SELECT 'ABC'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D_XYZ' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | YOUR_COLUMN |
> | --- |
> | ABC |
> | DEF |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d7185edcd1fdb7bb5cd4cccc522c869e)*